# Network overload of docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, tendermint

I am a beginner in using docker. I am running a blockchain (tendermint) simulation in my laptop using docker compose. Of all the transactions sent, only a very few transaction reaches all the servers. I am using four containers which communicate among themselves. Is it possible that the containers just drop the transactions when the rate at which the transactions are sent is too much for them to handle?

Comment: You can create a separate network in Docker that all services in a Docker Compose file can use without overlapping with other networks.